# how to test "render to template" functions in django? (TDD)

Tags: django, testing, tdd, django-views

How should I test these functions? All they do is render the html page and pass some objects to the html page.

```
def index(request):
    companies = Company.objects.filter(approved = True);
    return direct_to_template(request, 'home.html', {'companies': companies} );
```

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I've never done TDD so I am not even sure where to start.

Comment: I took a look at [Toast Driven](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/apr/10/guide-to-testing-in-django/) when I started with TDD. There are a whole bunch of guides knocking around on the internet.

Comment: @jvc26 ive went through some of Toast, but i still feel confused at what/when to test something..

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One could test the following:

1. Response code
2. Template used
3. Template contains some specific text

The code would look something like this:

```py
    from django.test import Client, TestCase
    from django.urls import reverse
    
    class TestPage(TestCase):
    
       def setUp(self):
           self.client = Client()
    
       def test_index_page(self):
           url = reverse('index')
           response = self.client.get(url)
           self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
           self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'index.html')
           self.assertContains(response, 'Company Name XYZ')
```

Comment: hi, what would this kind of test be considered? is this a acceptance test or a unit test? sorry i was never taught how to do testing. thank you for your help!

Comment: This would be a systems test. Try this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ickNQcNXiS4